# calling javascript method to change object property

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

I am trying to call the setAge function in the below code, to change bob's age to 50... but I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
// here we define our method using "this", before we even introduce bob
var setAge = function (newAge) {
  this.age = newAge;
};
// now we make bob
var bob = new Object();
bob.age = 30;
// and down here we just use the method we already made
bob.setAge = setAge;

// change bob's age to 50 here using the setAge function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `setAge` isn't on `bob`'s prototype chain, you'll have to use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call the function and specify that you want `bob` to be the `thisArg`:

```
setAge.call( bob, 50 );
```